# Incorrect sum in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a formula to calculate hours before and after certain times in google sheet. When i mark several cells I get the wrong sum in the right corner. All times are in format duration. When I use the function "sum" I do get the correct sum, but not when I mark the cells. I don't understand what the issue is, does anyone know what I could do to solve this problem?
See picture down below, "om" means "if".[image]